# File that runs a terminal command in OSX

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm trying to make it easier for a non-techy person to deploy to heroku.

In order to commit you make a git-push, like this:

```
git commit -a -m "autocommit"
git push heroku master
```

The end user of this solution isn't very comfortable with terminal commands. 
Is it possible to create a file that, once double-clicked will trigger theese commands in the terminal?

Comment: I think there are enough complex problems that can possibly occur with any git repo that just making it easy to commit changes won't solve all your issues.  Down the road your non-techy user will need expert help.

Comment: Yes, I know, this is for a very specific case. They are just swapping an image every day for a week. It's not ideal, but it's in a hurry. (I've heard that one before)

Comment: And you can't just create a simple shell script for this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up naming the file deploy.command. After that I went to the terminal and executed chmod +x deploy.command

that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, through Automator or AppleScript.  Both can be saved as self-executables that run terminal commands.